# How to organize this type of list in alphabetical order by the name key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I'm using python 3**

I was able to create a list with dictionaries,
now I need to sort by the "name" key in alphabetical order.

```
contact= [
    {
        'name': 'Jhon',
        'id': 18,
        'tel': "11111111111"
    }, {
        'name': 'Brian',
        'id': 56,
        'tel': "2222222222"
    }, {
        'name': 'Adrian',
        'id': 20,
        'tel': "3000000000"
    }
]
```

The result should look like this:

```
contact= [
    {
        'name': 'Adrian',
        'id': 20,
        'tel': "3000000000"
    }, {
        'name': 'Brian',
        'id': 56,
        'tel': "2222222222"
    },{
        'name': 'Jhon',
        'id': 18,
        'tel': "11111111111"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please repeat you tutorial on sorting.  You need to specify a key function using `entry["name"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
contact_sorted = [y for y in sorted(contact,key= lambda x:x['name'])]
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the list comprehension, `sorted` returns a list.

Comment: True, that's my bad, `sorted(contact,key= lambda x:x['name'])` works fine.